# What's the right idiomatic way to destruct a tuple where only some of values will create new variable in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I often find myself writing code that looks like this:

```
function example(parameter: string) {
    const tuple = [
        "newParameterValue",
        "newVariableValue"
    ]
    let newVar;
    [parameter, newVar] = tuple;
}
```

(Realistically, it also always involves async/await and `Promise.all`, and I run into these situations where I run several async operations in parallel, but these details are not relevant to this question). Important part is, I have to destruct a tuple, and assign one value from it to an existing variable, but create a new variable for another value.

It works, but I don't like that I have to define `newVar` with `let` instead of `const`, and that I have to separate it's declaration and assignment. It just looks wrong and dirty. What I would love to do instead is something akin to this:

```
function example(parameter: string) {
    const tuple = [
        "newParameterValue",
        "newVariableValue"
    ]
    [parameter, const newVar] = tuple;
}
```

But obviously, it doesn't compile.

What's a correct and idiomatic way to write this code?

Answer (score 0):

without knowing how you will use it - [should be const](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#let-vs-const), but what version you are using?

[in latest version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgCm3QCctkpkSAuRAZyhJjAHMBKRAbwChE-EICBoigg8yRAF5EAbV78FAIjDIA7gAVS5SiQBq6XCGSKANPIV9la-U3QAjfPsPHziALquZxMpgpUTAkJQiCqqNm5SImL4ANzcAL5AA) example can't be transpiled properly, and assigning to function parameter looks not good

```
  function example(parameter: string) {
    const tuple: [string, string] = [
        "newParameterValue",
        "newVariableValue"
    ];
    const [newParameter, newVar] = tuple;
  }
```